# Having a issue with my custom API that uses discord API

Tags: python, discord, fastapi, embed

This my first post on here but I’m having some issues with my code. It was working before but now it’s not? Every time submit the API request it tells me the header is incorrect even when I’m putting it in correctly. In this case it’s using the discord API so I make sure to use “Bot” in front of my token.

```
# Define the JSON model for the Discord embed request body
class DiscordEmbed(BaseModel):
    title: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="Title of the embed")
    description: str = Field(None, description="Required - Description of the embed")
    url: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="URL of the embed")
    timestamp: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="ISO Timestamp of the embed")
    color: Optional[int] = Field(None, description="Color code of the embed")
    footer_text: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="Footer text")
    footer_icon: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="URL of footer icon")
    author_text: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="Author name")
    author_icon: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="URL of author icon")
    image_url: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="URL of the image")
    thumbnail_url: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="URL of the thumbnail")

    def to_discord_embed(self):
        embed = {
            "title": self.title,
            "description": self.description,
            "url": self.url,
            "timestamp": self.timestamp,
            "color": self.color,
            "footer": {"text": self.footer_text, "icon_url": self.footer_icon},
            "author": {"name": self.author_text, "icon_url": self.author_icon},
            "image": {"url": self.image_url},
            "thumbnail": {"url": self.thumbnail_url}
        }
        return {"embeds": [embed]}

@app.post("/embed/{channel_id}")
async def embed_builder(channel_id: str, embed: DiscordEmbed, authorization: str = Header(...)):
    discord_api_url = f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channel_id}/messages"
    authorization = authorization
    if not authorization or not authorization.startswith("Bot "):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Unauthorized")

    headers = {
        "Authorization": authorization,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    discord_embed = embed.to_discord_embed()
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.post(discord_api_url, headers=headers, json=discord_embed)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=response.status_code, detail=response.json())

    message_id = response.json().get("id")
    return {"message": "Embed posted successfully.", "message_id": message_id}
  # ----------- //// end of embed builder //
```

To send an embed message to a discord channel with my custom API.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  "It was working before but now it's not" type of questions would mean you either changed something or something in the api was changed.  If it is telling you the header is incorrect, then check if your header has the correct fields and values.

Comment: Please attach the response get when trying to use this endpoint